# Python 3.6. I cannot add path directory under Mac os

Tags: python

I am mac os user and i am new to python3.
I created package. Python do not recognize the module from package because i guess directory was not saved for that package.

this is how I did for adding new directory.

1) open terminal and type

```
nano .bash_profile
```

2) type and save

```
PYTHONPATH=“${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/hunminpak/Documents/game/sound/ export PYTHONPATH”
```

3) In Python, typed

```
import game.sound

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    import game.sound
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'game.sound'
```

Please help me why my directory was not added.

Comment: move `export PYTHONPATH` onto a new line *outside* of any quotes

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in your second command. Change it from

```
PYTHONPATH=“${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/hunminpak/Documents/game/sound/ export PYTHONPATH”
```

to two commands.

First command (remove the trailing /): `PYTHONPATH=“${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/hunminpak/Documents/game/sound"`

Hit enter and then type second command:

```
export PYTHONPATH
```